# jQuery: Selector to use 'logical AND' over the same attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having something like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="http://a.site.org/a_link.html"></a>
    <a href="http://a.site.org/file_name.rdf"></a>
    <a href="http://a.site.org/file_features_name.rdf"></a>
    <a href="http://a.site.org/file_features2_name.rdf"></a>
</div>
```

How can I get only those links where the `href` attribute ends with `rdf` AND doesn't  contain `features`?

I know I can use:

```
$('a[href$=".rdf"]')
```

to get all the .rdf files. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use this:

```
$('a[href$=".rdf"]').not('[href*=features]')
```

Also can be written as one selector with:

```
$('a[href$=".rdf"]:not([href*=features])')
```

But I think it is less readable.

As always *code for humans not for machines*.

Comment: @KevinB, efficiency is negligible here, not my case at all.

Answer (score 3):

Add on the `:not(..)` selector:

```
$('a[href$=".rdf"]:not([href*="features"])')
```